# Which open source IoT board would be appropriate for a surveillance tool?

Tags: smart-home, hardware, digital-cameras

In the sea of IoT boards I would like to ask some advice regarding buying a board.

- Should be fast and compact (not Arduino)
- Open source hardware
- Should have Wi-Fi on board
- Should not have Ethernet connection
- Strong enough to run a simple application that streams video data to a remote Wi-Fi storage location
- SDK that runs on Mac
- Strong enough to run motion detection algorithms
- Pricing below 100 US dollars or Euros
- Be able to add extra sensors or modules

Are there any specific boards that meet these criteria?

My ultimate goal is to build a video surveillance tool for my personal use at home. It should be able to get input from a HD camera, run motion detection algorithm and strong enough to save the data stream to a Wi-Fi connected network share. Preferably something with a great SDK/IDE that runs on macOS also.

Ideally, it should also have an open source cloud server to connect the hardware to.

Comment: Just for interest, could you please explain why you don’t want Ethernet and if you would be willing to accept it on a board which fulfilled all of your other criteria?

Comment: If you have sugesstion with eth that should be ok perhaps it can be removed

Comment: I was thinking Rasberry PI, Orange PI or Banana PI, or maybe Chip.

Answer (score 6):

It may be useful for you to consult [Bence Kaulics' guide to selecting a microcontroller](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/881/12), which takes into account many constraints such as processing power, energy usage and developer tools. It's a good read with a lot of valuable information on the selection process.

However, I don't think you're really looking for a *microcontroller*; a [single-board computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-board_computer) would suit your needs far better in my view.

The [Raspberry Pi 3 Model B](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/processor-microcontroller-development-kits/8968660/) seems to meet most of your requirements. It meets almost all of your requirements, except:

- it **does** have an Ethernet port, when you said you didn't want it.
- there is [hardware documentation provided](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/), but the [SoC documentation is not great](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45759/where-can-i-find-the-documentation-for-the-bcm2837), and it is [not technically open source](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/which-open-source-iot-board-would-be-appropriate-for-a-surveillance-tool#comment1786_1080).

It should be relatively easy to extend with extra sensors or modules; there are plenty of [HATs](https://shop.pimoroni.com/collections/hats) available, and if you need to create something specifically for your device, you can [take advantage of the GPIO pins and a breadboard](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-guide/connect-leds/).

The board is well within your cost constraints (£32.99 in the UK as of February 2017), and the processor should be powerful enough for your use case.

As for the cloud platform, [AWS IoT seems to integrate relatively well](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdk-setup.html) with the Raspberry Pi, although of course the cloud platform is **not** open source.

For development, you should be able to use `ssh` in your macOS terminal to connect directly to the Raspberry Pi. From there, you can use all the usual Unix terminal utilities and programs.

Comment: The Raspberry is not truly open source, i.e. full schematics are not available for Pi3 and it uses a closed source GPU. Other than that a Pi could be a good *thing* for this task. The OP might want to join: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Any Cortex-M3 device would seem to be suitable. M4 and M7 are available with more processing power. This will give a far lower power solution than R-Pi. Yes, it will be a SBC, otherwise known as an eval board, but probably not meeting the open-hardware requirement unless you build your own PCB.

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking at the CHIP Pro,
this board seems to almost nail it except the problem that there are no camera drivers for the onboard camera connectors.

A USB camera could work, but its not really neat to generate a production version with an usb powered camera I think?

One could hot glue the board with the USB connector together but still I think this is not a really good solution and an integrated camera would be the best option.

The raspberry seems to nail it almost except the hardware is not truly opensource ( the CHIP Pro is, it seems)

Perhaps there is even a better board I have to investigate before buying one.